# How to pass file information with a xmlhttp request

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make a file upload thing for my messaging system.
I use a file input type and I am using javascript to transmit the file name, tmp, ext etc...
This is my javascript :

```
document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var file = this.files[0];

  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("file", file);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var group_id = document.getElementById('group_id').value;
  var fullurl = '../backend/sendvideosandimages.php?id=' + group_id;
    xhr.open('POST', fullurl, true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (this.status == 200) {
      };
  };

  xhr.send(fd);
  }, false);
};
```

The problem is that it says (in the console) that it successfully loads the url BUT my php never receives the file data. My php code in case you need it :

```
<?php

session_start();
include_once '../backend/messagingfunctions.php';
include_once '../backend/databaseconn.php';
$errors= array();
$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$file_name)));

$extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","mp4","MP4","MOV","PNG","JPG","mov","JPEG");

if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
   $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG, PNG or a MP4 file type!";
}

if($file_size > 16777216) {
   $errors[]='File size must be at MOST 16 MB!';
}

if(empty($errors)==true) {
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,'../userfiles/'.$file_name);
    $fileplace = '../userfiles/'.$file_name;
    if ($fileplace != null) {
      if ($file_ext == "mp4" || "mov" || "MOV" || "MP4") {
        $date = date("y-m-d h:i:s");
        $filetype = "video";
        $myId = $_SESSION['user-id'];
        $message = $fileplace;
        $groupId = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);
        addMessage($myId, $groupId, $date, $message, $filetype);
      } elseif ($file_ext == "jpg" || "jpeg" || "png" || "PNG" || "JPG" || "JPEG") {
      $date = date("y-m-d h:i:s");
      $filetype = "image";
      $myId = $_SESSION['user-id'];
      $message = $fileplace;
      $groupId = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);
      addMessage($myId, $groupId, $date, $message, $filetype);
    }

}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On the face of it the JavaScript part looks okay, although you have an extraneous `};` at the end, and with all due respect, it's pretty hard to read code with semi-random indentation.

Comment: ok, I'll fix that, do you know what caused the issue though?

Comment: JS code works as expected, and PHP also receives the file for me; you need to debug your PHP code to determine where exactly it fails.